# Return wrong query when fields type of timestamp using NestJs + PostgreSQL + Typeorm

Tags: postgresql, timezone, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to know if you have already faced the following challenge: I have a NestJs application with PostgreSQL and typeorm for ORM. It's something pretty silly in real, but it's giving work lol. When I make query the time zone is changed, will add automaticamentily +3 hours in all fields of type timestamp/timestamptz.

I added the TZ=America_Sao_Paulo and even then the query keeps changing the time zone. On the other hand, if I change it to TZ=UTC, a query returns what is expected, but at each new Date() I will not have the local time zone (Brazil). Did you understand? Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that dealing with timestamps can be difficult, and the problem you're having with time zone changes in your NestJS application utilising PostgreSQL and TypeORM is a frequent one. In PostgreSQL, time zone conversion is carried out during queries or displays, and timestamps are stored by default in UTC.

Make sure your PostgreSQL server's time zone is appropriately set by entering something like `TZ=America_Sao_Paulo` in the database setup to address this. When interacting with timestamps in your NestJS application, be sure to use `toLocaleString` to explicitly set the proper time zone after creating a new timestamp using `new Date()`.

To keep the application and the database consistent, be sure to change the TypeORM configuration's `timezone` option to match your preferred time zone `"America/Sao_Paulo"`. By doing this, you'll be able to maintain accurate time zone conversions and prevent unexpected changes in time zone offsets when your application interacts with timestamps.